# SQL Server : error which works well in Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I'm migrating from an Oracle database to SQL Server 2012. Some SQL which works well in Oracle doesn't work with SQL Server.

The following is my SQL and the error.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(COUNT(DISTINCT dfc.rentalNumber)) 
FROM 
    DueFromClient dfc 
WHERE 
    dfc.facilityId=:facilityId 
    AND dfc.isRentalComponent = 1 
GROUP BY 
    dfc.rentalNumber
```

and the error is

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery

Comment: why would you be summing a count? if you want to know the number of rows just do the COUNT

Comment: This will give you a column with `1` values, for as many distinct rental numbers you have in your table. Why?

Comment: You could capsulate everthing except the sum in a subquery, and then sum the result...

Comment: I've added additional versions of query to fix your error with SUM(COUNT(DISTINCT dfc.rentalNumber)) construction and also I've added sqlfiddles for all of queries, including your original, so you can be sure what same results returned by all of them

Comment: Thank you I understood the problem and fixed it with your ideas

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to sum count and group by. Try this:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT dfc.rentalNumber) 
FROM 
    DueFromClient dfc 
WHERE 
    dfc.facilityId=:facilityId 
    AND dfc.isRentalComponent = 1
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/324a5e/1) for this query

All of proposed below are suboptimal and returns same result as query above, but they may meet needs of @Sachi Pj with using of same construction as in original query with SUM(COUNT(DISTINCT()) two more options:

```
SELECT SUM(dfc2.rentalNumber)
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        COUNT(DISTINCT dfc.rentalNumber) rentalNumber
    FROM 
        DueFromClient dfc 
    WHERE 
        dfc.facilityId=:facilityId 
        AND dfc.isRentalComponent = 1 
) AS dfc2
GROUP BY dfc2.rentalNumber
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/74d76/2) for this query

And without GROUP BY since doubles was eliminated by distinct:

```
SELECT SUM(dfc2.rentalNumber)
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        COUNT(DISTINCT dfc.rentalNumber) rentalNumber
    FROM 
        DueFromClient dfc 
    WHERE 
        dfc.facilityId=:facilityId 
        AND dfc.isRentalComponent = 1 
) AS dfc2
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/74d76/1) for this query

You can compare with your original query [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c76d9/3) to being sure what the results are same.

Comment: Maybe he does need the `GROUP BY`? We don't know for sure.

Comment: No, group by is not necessary in this case for sure. I've tested this

Comment: I'm not saying your query is incorrect, it will compile and run but we don't know if this is what `OP` wants to see, what is the expected result.

Comment: It will return a count of unique rentalNumber in 
SELECT rentalNumber
FROM 
    DueFromClient dfc 
WHERE 
    dfc.facilityId=:facilityId 
    AND dfc.isRentalComponent = 1 
GROUP BY 
    dfc.rentalNumber

Like your original query in Oracle, 
The original query is suboptimal. So, it's better to change to optimized query in Oracle too

Comment: So I just get rid of SUM? This is not a query I wrote, I'm assigned to fix some errors, so I was assuming the person meant something when he had both sum and count.

Comment: Added fix without optimization, but believe me, all these 3 queries give the same result. So it is better to use optimal one. I've even tested all of them to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `SUM` from the query, as it has no use, since you are also using `GROUP BY`. The results will be the same as your original query.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT dfc.rentalNumber)
FROM DueFromClient dfc 
WHERE dfc.facilityId = facilityId 
    AND dfc.isRentalComponent = 1 
GROUP BY dfc.rentalNumber
```

This doesn't make much sense, so I suggest also adding the `rentalNumber` to the `SELECT` in order to make sense of your data and to also make full use of the `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT dfc.rentalNumber)
    , dfc.rentalNumber
FROM DueFromClient dfc 
WHERE dfc.facilityId = facilityId 
    AND dfc.isRentalComponent = 1 
GROUP BY dfc.rentalNumber
```